# Make a function of multiple arguments in pandas

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'a':range(6),'b':range(6)})
```

I create a 'c' columns and filter values by this code:

```
data['c']=0
data.c[(data.a<=3)&(data.b<=3)]='small'
data.c[(data.a>3)&(data.b>3)]='big'
```

Is there any way to create a function like def(x,y,z) (x,y,z are equivalent to a,b,c),similar to this:

```
def(x,y,z):
   if(x<=3)&(y<=3):
      z='small'
   if(x>3)& (y>3):
      z='big'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must write a function then you can use `apply` with `axis=1` which will pass each row as a series to the calling function.

```
def func(row):
   if(row.a<=3)&(row.b<=3):
       return 'small'
   elif(row.a>3)& (row.b>3):
       return 'big'
   else:
       return 'something else'

data['c'] = data.apply(func, axis=1)
```

You can just use `np.where`. No need to write a function

```
data['c'] = np.where((data.a > 3) & (data.b >3), 'big', 'small')

   a  b      c
0  0  0  small
1  1  1  small
2  2  2  small
3  3  3  small
4  4  4    big
5  5  5    big
```

Comment: The example is just an overly-simplified version. Things I need is to write a function with some arguments then I can apply it to other data.

Comment: Tks a lot, but it is not really what I needed. For example, if I come accross a data with x( equivalent to a) and y( equivalent to b), so how can I call this function?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Update your question with better data.

Comment: Just answered the question by myself. In fact, the solution was answered in SO before. Tks a lot for ur numpy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You almost did it:

```
def func(data,x,y,z):
    if (data[x]<=3)&(data[y]<=3):
        data[z]="small"
    #etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tks for all answers. It did help me a lot! After turning around the function, I came up with approach of nested function. It took the whole dataframe as an object (x):

```
def func(x,y):
if (x<=3)&(y<=3):
    return 'small'
else:
    return'big'

data['c']=data.apply(lambda x:func(x['a'],x['b']),axis=1)
```

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding `apply`.  This answer is the same as my first answer only with more code. Read the docs